# timeit autorange returns much faster

Tags: python

I ran a benchmark and it took approximately 6 seconds to run. timeit autorange took a total of 6 seconds instead of 60. It would usually take 60 seconds. Has things changed?

P.S- I am using Python 3.7.0 alpha 1

Comment: A lot of things have changed. Anything you had in mind specifically? P.S- add the code.

Comment: Right. I agree with @PadraicCunningham. Your question seems rather unclear to me. But if it is `timeit autorange` that you are asking about, you could see [this page](http://bugs.python.org/issue28240). 
timeit autorange now uses a single loop iteration if the benchmark takes less than 10 seconds, instead of 10 iterations. “python3 -m timeit -s ‘import time’ ‘time.sleep(1)’” now takes 4 seconds instead of 40 seconds.

Comment: I guess you are asking about changes between 3.6 and 3.7.0 alpha 1? How about a runnable example?

Comment: I didn't know that.Thanks for the links @jiltedpotato

Comment: Yes I wanted to know the changes they made to timeit

Comment: I think that could be the answer @jiltedpotato Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems rather unclear to me. But if it is `timeit autorange` that you are asking about, you could see [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue28240) page. timeit autorange now uses a single loop iteration if the benchmark takes less than 10 seconds, instead of 10 iterations. `“python3 -m timeit -s ‘import time’ ‘time.sleep(1)’”` now takes 4 seconds instead of 40 seconds